# phpExcel in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

i try to get excel file and cover it to pdf. i succes but i not see the data and is tell me cant load the data to the pdf

here my code:

```
        //load our new PHPExcel library
    $this->load->library('excel');

    $inputFileName = 'nameoffile';
    $excel2 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
    $excel2 = $excel2->load($inputFileName.'.xls');
    $excel2->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Type: application/download');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=from-template.pdf");
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel2, 'pdf');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: What is the actual error message that you're getting?

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel_Writer_xls' not found

Comment: The code that you've posted should generate that error; you're trying to create a `pdf` Writer, not an `xls` Writer

Comment: so how i can do that?

Comment: Don't use the same variable for the Reader, and for the Spreadsheet file that you're reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps that's because there isn't a `PHPExcel_Writer_xls`, there is, however a `PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5` that you should be using if you're trying to write BIFF-format `.xls` files

However, your code shows that you're trying to create a PDF writer. Filenames are "case-sensitive", so to create a `PDF` Writer you need to specify it in upper-case

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel2, 'PDF');
```

**EDIT**

Don't use the same variable for your reader as for your spreadsheet

```
$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName . '.xls');

header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="from-template.pdf"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT'); // always modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'PDF');
$writer->save('php://output');
die();
```

Comment: how i can do from excel to pdf?

Comment: You load the file exactly as you are loading it, with the `Excel5` Reader, then save it with the `PDF` Writer

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel_Writer_xls' not found in F:\wamp\www\project3\application\third_party\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php on line 141

Comment: OK, you've broken me..... I haven't a clue why it's trying to find a file that doesn't exist.... `PHPExcel_Writer_xls` does not exist, has never existed, and I can't see anyway that the code should ever try to look for it

Comment: What PDF renderer are you using, and how have you configured it?

Comment: i use only PHPExce i need PDF?

Comment: See section 6.9 of the [Developer documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/10-Reading-and-Writing.md) entitled `PDF`. PHPExcel provides wrappers to work with either [tcPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/), [DomPDF](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) or [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/) as a rendering engine, but doesn't actually include any of those libraries. They need to be installed separately, and then you configure PHPExcel to indicate which one you're using, and where you've installed it

Comment: Can you explain to me how it works with CODEIGNITER?
Because it still does not work by the instructors there.

Comment: I can't explain what you'd need to do in CI because I'm not familiar with CI

Answer (score 0):

this working very code. so how i covert this.

```
        //load our new PHPExcel library
    $this->load->library('excel');

    $inputFileName = 'nameoffile';
    $reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
    $spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName . '.xls');

    header('Content-Type: application/xls');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="from-template.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
```

// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
        header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
        header ('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT'); // always modified
        header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
        header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

```
    $writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Excel5');
    $writer->save('php://output');
    die();
```